# What happens to a long-running request when session expires?

Tags: http, session, servlets

I would like to understand the internals of Session~setMaxInactiveInterval

I understand that if HTTP requests are not received within the said interval then the session is cleared. All the objects belonging to the session will be gone.

Does that also mean that the existing requests part of the session will be terminated ?

I have scenario for large file transfer to happen over a single request.

So if one request (A) is long running and there are no other requests sent within the time interval. Then will the request A will be terminated ?

Best Regards,

Saurav